# Are there any libraries for non binary decision trees in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I am looking for some library that has an implementation for Non Binary Decision Tree algorithm.
For example I want to classify zoo set(https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/zoo-animal-classification/data) using some decision tree algorithm.
So far I have found about sklearn method(DecisionTreeClassifier):

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

But it builds binary tree:
[image: Part of result tree]

And zoo set has categorical data, so I think it is better to use here non binary tree(it's not a point, but please correct me if I'm wrong).
So my question is: **Are there any libs in Python to build a decision tree like on following picture:**
[image: part of non binary decision tree for zoo dataset]

It's ok even if output without applying any drawing tools will be as a simple dictionary, like this one:

```
{'legs': {0: {'fins': {0.0: {'toothed': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 3.0}},
                       1.0: {'eggs': {0.0: 1.0, 1.0: 4.0}}}},
          2: {'hair': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}},
          4: {'hair': {0.0: {'aquatic': {0.0: 3.0,
                                         1.0: {'toothed': {0.0: 7.0,
                                                           1.0: 5.0}}}},
                       1.0: 1.0}},
          5: 7.0,
          6: {'aquatic': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}},
          8: 7.0}}
```

Comment: Hi! did you find one??

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just a more specific way of representing a binary tree.

The tree that you have shown can be rewritten as a binary tree.

If you have categorical data, just use the `OneHotEncoder`.